# HTML string loads during second attempt in WebView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

I have this simple code:

```
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource { Html = @"<html>
                                                    <body>
                                                      Text
                                                    </body>
                                                  </html>" };
myWebView.Source = htmlSource;
```

`myWebView` is defined in my XAML code. The `WebView` loads when I click a button that runs the aforementioned code.

My problem is that the first time I click the button the `WebView` loads but it is empty. The second time I click the button the `WebView` loads and presents the HTML OK.

Any idea why the first time the `HTML string` does not load in the `WebView`?

Comment: There is nothing in the code you show that would explain that. Therefore, you need to show more xaml and code. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Make a simple `TestWebViewPage : ContentPage` with nothing but the WebView and the button. In App.xaml.cs, set `MainPage = new TestWebViewPage();` Then show the complete xaml and cs for that simple page. Test - verify that button has same "second time" behavior.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. I didn't respond immediately and till now I forgot to do it at all. I solved the problem by creating an HTML file that I have added to the app's assets. Loading the file does not face any problem, so I I don't intend to investigate the cause of the problem of the HTML string not loading at once.